# (Node.js) --grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node

I want to compile my .proto file into stubs, but when entering the command:

> `protoc -I=. ./protos/dummy.proto
>   --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./server --grpc_out=./server --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=which grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin

I got the following error :

```
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Thigs I have installed :

- Windows 10
- npm install **-g** grpc-tools
- npm install google-protobuf
- protoc

NOTE: I noticed there are a few similar questions already, but I didn't find one for Node.js, also the already asked questions all have different solutions.

Answer (score 11):

**On Windows**, I messed around with the `grpc-tools` for Node a bit and came across some issues. I installed the tools (and the TS plugin) via `npm install grpc-tools grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts --save-dev` to my local `node_modules/.bin` folder. Thanks to [this](https://github.com/improbable-eng/ts-protoc-gen/issues/100) post, I can provide these solutions. This was my original shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PROTO_DIR="./src/grpc/proto"
PROTOC_GEN_TS_PATH="./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts"
GRPC_TOOLS_NODE_PROTOC_PLUGIN="./node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin"
GRPC_TOOLS_NODE_PROTOC="./node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc"

# Generate JS and corresponding TS d.ts codes for each .proto file using the grpc-tools for Node.
$GRPC_TOOLS_NODE_PROTOC \
    --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="$GRPC_TOOLS_NODE_PROTOC_PLUGIN" \
    --plugin=protoc-gen-ts="$PROTOC_GEN_TS_PATH" \
    --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:"$PROTO_DIR" \
    --ts_out="$PROTO_DIR" \
    --grpc_out="$PROTO_DIR" \
    -I "$PROTO_DIR" \
    "$PROTO_DIR"/*.proto
```

1. If you just provide the plugin by its name, e.g. `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=./node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin`, Windows will complain about an invalid Win32 application. You can solve this issue by adding the `.cmd` extension:

`--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=./node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin.cmd`

2. Unfortunately, the following issue `'.' Not an internal or external command, or a runnable program or batch file` arises, which indicates that Windows cannot resolve the relative path to the plugin. Therefore, you have to provide the absolute path, e.g.

`--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=C:/.../<project-dir>/node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin.cmd`

**Now the *real magic* happens:**

Because of a simple typo (I typed `--plugin=proto-gen-grpc` instead of `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc`), I figured out that, if you have `grpc-tools` and additional plugins installed in your local Node environment, you can simply omit `--plugin`.
It seems that `grpc_tools_node_protoc` will automatically lookup the executables required to generate the code specified by the output flags `--grpc_out`, `--js_out` or `--ts_out` in `./node_modules/.bin/`.

Therefore, I updated the following LOC in my script

```
$GRPC_TOOLS_NODE_PROTOC \
    --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:"$PROTO_DIR" \
    --ts_out="$PROTO_DIR" \
    --grpc_out="$PROTO_DIR" \
    -I "$PROTO_DIR" \
    "$PROTO_DIR"/*.proto
```

Maybe, others could share their experience and more clarifications to this issue.

Comment: This only worked for me if I installed grpc-tools and grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts globally with `npm install -g grpc-tools grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts`

Comment: First version of script is misleading, it doesnt work and fails with the error OP mentions, but once read to the end of post:) and replacing with final version of script it finally worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can solve this issue by adding the .cmd extension:

> --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=./node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin.cmd

2. And the following issue '.' Not an internal or external command, or a runnable program or batch file, you can solve replacing the '.' by '%cd%':

> --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=%cd%/node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin.cmd

Answer (score 0):

**SIMPLE SOLUTION :**

For me the "which" command was pointing to the wrong path so I removed it and replaced it with an absolute path to the plugin instead. It looks like this :

> protoc -I=. ./protos/dummy.proto
>   --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./server --grpc_out=./server --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grpc-tools\bin\grpc_node_plugin.exe

**Explanation :**

I am not sure why this error (--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: %1 is not a valid Win32 application) was happening, but I have an theory... The "which" command pointed to the folder and not to the .exe file. How do I know this? When I try to only run the command (in the terminal)

```
which grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin
```

It returns the folder

> /c/Users/myUser/AppData/Roaming/npm/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin

Answer (score 0):

As `grpc-tools` has been installed globally (`-g` flag per OP), setting the plugin path beforehand works.

```
    GRPC_TOOLS_PLUGIN="$HOME/AppData/Roaming/npm/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin.cmd" && \
protoc -I=. ./protos/*.proto \
--js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./server \
--grpc_out=./server \
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$GRPC_TOOLS_PLUGIN
```

Thanks to both answers before me for pointers! 
Tested and found to be working on **Windows 10 Pro** and **Git Bash**.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code worked for me.

```
protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./server ./proto/dummy.proto
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CDPath=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")";pwd)

SRC_DIR="./src/proto"
OUT_DIR="./src/proto/generated"

rm -rf ${OUT_DIR}
mkdir ${OUT_DIR}

PROTOC_PATH=${CDPath}/node_modules/grpc-tools/bin/protoc
PROTOC_GEN_TS_PATH=${CDPath}/node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts.cmd

GRPC_TOOLS_NODE_PROTOC=${CDPath}/node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc.cmd
GRPC_TOOLS_NODE_PROTOC_PLUGIN=${CDPath}/node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin.cmd

#Generate JS and corresponding TS d.ts codes for each .proto file using the grpc-tools for Node.
${GRPC_TOOLS_NODE_PROTOC} \
    --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${GRPC_TOOLS_NODE_PROTOC_PLUGIN}" \
    --plugin=protoc-gen-ts="${PROTOC_GEN_TS_PATH}" \
    --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:"$OUT_DIR" \
    --ts_out="$OUT_DIR" \
    --grpc_out="$OUT_DIR" \
    -I "$SRC_DIR" \
    "$SRC_DIR"/*.proto

# generate d.ts codes
${PROTOC_PATH} --plugin=protoc-gen-ts="${PROTOC_GEN_TS_PATH}" \
    --ts_out=grpc_js:"$OUT_DIR" \
    -I "$SRC_DIR" \
    "$SRC_DIR"/*.proto
```